# Is direct limit of injective étale sheaves injective?

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, schemes, injective-module

Is the following statement true? if so where can I find a proof for reference purposes?

- Direct limit of injective étale sheaves of abelian groups on a Noetherian scheme is injective.

This goes back whether the extension property of being injective can be checked over finitely presented sheaves or not. I was not able to figure that out.

Upon writing this question it was suggested to me to checkout the Hartshorne's chapter III problem 2.6. Which is not about étale sheaves but rather sheaves on Noetherian topological spaces. Furthermore the exercise seems to be incorrect (at least the hint is incorrect not sure about the statement of the exercise itself). You can read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587916/what-is-a-finitely-generated-sheaf) post to realize why it is incorrect.

Comment: The Hartshorne exercise you mention came up earlier this year [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360445/mathscri-is-injective-iff-for-every-u-subseteq-x-r-subseteq-mathbbz/4360456#4360456) and is basically fine once you adjust the meaning of "finitely generated" appropriately.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the link. I was thinking the correct notion of finite generation here is that $\mathbb{Z}_U$ are Noetherian objects. So the category of sheaves on that particular topological space admit a set of generators consisting of Noetherian objects. Hence the category is locally Noetherian. It is known in locally Noetherian categories filtered colimit of injective objects is injective. I believe this argument generalizes to the etale case too.